# UTC date not changing in IST date format in PHP

Tags: php, date, format, utc, strtotime

As based on REST API page [documentation](https://documentation.unicommerce.com/docs/notes-for-reader.html) the date is in UTC format as `yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm:ss (Eg: 2017-01-02T08:12:53)`
When I hit the API, I am getting the date as `1619693307000`. Converted this date using `strtotime()` in PHP.
What is the correct way to convert this date in `d-m-Y h:i:s IST` in PHP.

I used this code to do the same.

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s", '1619693307000') ?> //OUTPUT: 53296-01-14 01:00:00
```

The above output is absolutely wrong.
Confusion is to correctly convert UTC to IST zone and what should i do to see the correct output as the date in PHP. I read all threads on this StackOverflow and Google.
but all not helpfull.

Please help...

Comment: Are you sure when converting strtotime('2017-01-02T08:12:53') evaluates to 1619693307000. Since when i tried it i got the correct date and time. Could you please share the strtotime() part of the code.

Comment: That timestamp you have is in milliseconds and PHP expects seconds. Divide by 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timestamp has too many digits, so it's likely in milliseconds. This seems to be a common javascript thing. So divide by 1000, and I highly recommend using the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) objects/interfaces rather than the old-style `strtotime()`/`date()`/etc functions.

```php
$millis = 1619693307000;
$seconds = $millis / 1000;

$t = new DateTime('', new DateTimezone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$t->setTimestamp($seconds);

var_dump(
    $t->format("Y-m-d h:i:s T")
);
```

Output:

```
string(23) "2021-04-29 04:18:27 IST"
```

Also "UTC" is not a format, it's a timezone. `2017-01-02T08:12:53` is an ISO8601-format. It also has a handy format shortcut:

```php
var_dump(
    $t->format("c")
);
```

Output:

```
string(25) "2021-04-29T16:18:27+05:30"
```

**Edit:** Different timezone and format:

```php
$t = new DateTime('', new DateTimezone('UTC'));
$t->setTimestamp($seconds);

var_dump(
    $t->format("Y-m-d\Th:i:s")
);
```

Output:

```
string(19) "2021-04-29T10:48:27"
```

Comment: thank you, help me, why we save UTC formate in the database? and what is the way we can convert the date in UTC same as my question date and save in the database

Comment: Storing and computing dates as UTC is generally regarded as best practice because UTC is an international standard and will never be subject to rules like daylight savings or interference from any one government. I'll tack on an extra example for switching up the TZ and format.

Comment: It means we always save the date in DB in UTC? for a good experience? and is this right to convert the date in UTC ? `<?= strtotime(date('2021-05-06 11:41:12')) * 1000; ?>`